# Are the set of finitely supported probability measure in Euclidean space compact?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose X is a compact subset of Euclidean Space. Let P(X) be the set of all Borel probability measures on X. Now let's consider the set of all Borel probability measures on X with finite support. My question is: is this subset compact? Or consider the set of all Borel probability measures on X with the cardinality of the support bounded above by some fix number K. Then is this set compact?

Comment: What have you tried? There are easy answers to some of yuor questions. In partucular you can see thai: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112825/set-of-all-probability-measures-with-finite-support?rq=1

Comment: What topology are you considering on $P(X)$?

Comment: You can construct a sequence of  Borel probability measures that converges weakly to a Borel probability measure without any mass points. Actually, every Borel probability measure is the weak limit of a sequence of finite support probability measures with values in the support, but that is harder to show. If you allow for a finite upper bound on the support, you actually get a compact set.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelGreinecker!